# String read from file not null terminating even after adding null terminator in c?

Tags: c, string, file, parsing, io

Let me preface this with the fact that I have looked at other relevant stack overflow questions but all of them simply say to add the null terminator, which I have been doing so I have no idea what is going on.

I'm writing an opengl program and need to parse the shaders taken from other files into strings so opengl can do its magic with them. However, I'm having trouble writing a very very basic file parser in c for some reason. I was told that after reading in a file, you need to add your own terminating character to the end of the char array so I malloc'd one extra char and set that to '\0'. However, whenever I print out the string, I still get a trailing trash character that I'm assuming is just the ascii interpretation of whatever number happens to be at that memory location. Does anybody know how to fix this? I've tried adding more space, writing over the space, and more but don't really know what to do.

Here's the function:

```
char* parse_shader(const char* path)
{
    char* buffer = 0;
    long length = 0;
    //Look up how to read in from file
    FILE* source = fopen(path, "r");
    if(!source)
        ERROR_RETURN(NULL, "Failed to load source: %s\n", path);
    
    fseek(source, 0, SEEK_END);
    length = ftell(source);
    fseek(source, 0, SEEK_SET);
    buffer = malloc(length + 1);
    if(!buffer)
        ERROR_RETURN(NULL, "Failed to allocate memory for file: %s\n", path)
    fread(buffer, 1, length, source);

    buffer[length] = '\0';

    fclose(source);

    return buffer;
}
```

As you can see, the function takes in a path, finds the length of the file, mallocs the space with one extra byte for the null terminator, adds the stuff to the buffer and then makes the last index the null terminator. For some reason this doesn't work.

Here's an example output:

```
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in vec3 a_pos;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(a_pos, 1.0);
}╪
```

Edit:
After looking at the file further in a text editor and doing some debugging via printf, I found that it says the file is 112 bytes long but when added to the buffer it comes out to be 106 bytes.

After reading one of the comments, it seems to be because of windows storing the newlines in the file as "carriage return-newline pairs."

I'm assuming ftell() correctly gets the size of the file, which means it includes the \r, but when the string is read into the buffer, the \r is not included so there is extra space at the end of the buffer.

Does anybody know how to fix this.

As per another comments request, I am using gcc on windows.

Comment: Have you looked in the file itself, with for example a hex editor, to see what it really contains? Perhaps the extra bytes are in the original file?

Comment: Just looked in a hex editor and nothing past the last }

Comment: Note that [ftell](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ftell) only gives the file size in bytes when the file is opened in binary mode.

Comment: Are you on a Windows system, where newline in *files* are stored as a carriage return-newline pair, which will be translated into a single newline when you read from the file?

Comment: You need to provide the verbatim file you're reading. Or better a minimal file that reproduces the problem. Also tell us what platform/IDE/compiler/OS  you're on. [Edit] the question.

Comment: Your parse_shader() function is correct, can you check the code for outputting the data from the return value?

Comment: `fread` returns how many bytes it actually read, so you might be fine with `buffer[fread(...)] = 0;` – and you likely want to check `feof` and `ferror` to determine if reading actually was successful.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use fgets instead?

Comment: OT: Your function is rather badly named... It doesn't *parse* anything. And the file it loads could by *any* file, not just a shader file. Perhaps `read_file` might be a more suitable name? :)

Comment: I agree with @Aconcagua's suggestion to do `r = fread(…)` and then `buffer[r] = '\0';`.  You could also check to make sure `r <= length`, and complain loudly if it's not.